# Can anyone identify this component? B08 55L

Tags: solenoid-valve, gas

This is on a gas solenoid control circuit.  Glorified on and off switch, the only significant other bit in the circuit is a NAND switch dual Schmidt trigger IC.

The right leg is connected to ground, the tab is connected to the negative terminal of the gas valve line, and the right goes off to the circuitry around the IC.

It blew a 1A fuse while sitting in the off position and no one around.

The gas valve reads almost 4 ohms but being off it shouldn't have been an issue (fail safe solenoid,) but the control board itself reads 2 ohms across DC in.

That seems low. That would draw 6 amperes right?

[image]

Comment: If you are reading a short circuit across GV+ and GV-, then I'd take a look at D3.

Answer (score 4):

It's a 60V 12A MOSFET. [NTD3055L104, NTDV3055L104](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntd3055l104-d.pdf) manufactured in the 8th week of 2014.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing this is the culprit.

Comment: If Drain-Source measures short circuit in both polarities, it's the culprit.